# A hatching algorithm using lines parallel to X-axis

Tags: java, algorithm, graphics

I need an algorithm for hatching a random polygon with parallel to X-axis lines.
I started writing what I think is a solution.
My algorithm implementation is something like this **(bolded step probably not correct)**:

1. Determine the Y-axis levels for the lines using minY and maxY of the polygon
2. For each Y-axis level determine X coordinates of crossing points.
3. Sort the Xs of the crossing points for each level
4. **Draw lines on each level for each pair of Xs**

This is the result: [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiPWu.png)
I need a way to determine what is inside the polygon and what is not or at least what is the algorithm.
*(I know this is an existing alogirthm but I cannot find it anywhere)*

Comment: do you expect a polygon to have self-intersections?

Comment: you have no expectations it can be any kind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Determine the Y-axis levels for the lines using minY and maxY of the polygon
> 2. For each Y-axis level determine X coordinates of crossing points.
> 3. Sort the Xs of the crossing points for each level
> 4. Draw lines on each level for each pair of Xs

You have the right idea. Let's say that for step #3, you have a list of `xs = [x0, x1, x2, x3]`. Then you need to draw lines from `(x0, y)` to `(x1, y)` and from `(x2, y)` to `(x3, y)`. You don't want to draw a line from `(x1, y)` to `(x2, y)`.

If you look closely at the pattern, you should be able to generalize an algorithm to draw the line segments.

Answer (score 0):

For a bullet-proof solution:

```
For all equally spaced Y in the range Ymin to Ymax:
    Try all edges PiPj in turn (j is the successor of i):
        if (Y >= Yi) != (Y >= Yj):
            There is an intersection, compute and store the corresponding X
    Sort the X's left to right
    Draw all segments (X[2i], Y) to (X[2i+1], Y)
```

Be sure to write the intersection condition as above, this will guarantee an even number in all cases.

---

For a polygon of many sides, this is pretty inefficient as you scan the whole polygon for every level. A more efficient way is using a sweepline approach: sort the edges by increasing ordinate of the lowest endpoint. Then as you go increasing Y, you will maintain a list of edges that intersect the current Y. Every time you increase Y, you remove the edges with a lower upper endpoint, and insert the edges with a lower lower endpoint (if an edge meets the two conditions, it is just skipped).